# using the count function in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have got that statment:

```
       $result1=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'") or exit(mysql_error());
```

and I want to find the count this way:

```
   if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
   {
       $userNameResult=$row['COUNT(*)'];
   }
```

I think I am not doing it right? or am I? why do i put count(*) in the statment and in the row variable? why cant I put it once in either? instead of both..is that the way to do it.? is that the best practice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are doing works, but it might be better to create a column alias for `COUNT(*)` in the query, that you can reference in your fetch call. This is really only a readability improvement.

```
$result1=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS userCount FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'") or exit(mysql_error());
//------------------------------------^^^^^^^^

if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
    $userNameResult=$row['userCount'];
}
```

You could achieve the same thing without using a fetch call at all, if you modified your query to select all rows and then use `mysql_num_rows()`.  Which method is more efficient depends somewhat on the contents of your database.

```
$result1=mysql_query("SELECT user_name FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'");
// Echo the row count...
if ($result1) echo mysql_num_rows($result1);
```

Comment: "Which method is more efficient", my foot!

Answer (score 2):

Its always easier to alias the column like

```
$result1=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS userCount FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'") or exit(mysql_error());
if($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
   $userNameResult=$row['userCount'];
}
```

or just use a numeric array

```
$result1=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS userCount FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'") or exit(mysql_error());
if($row=mysql_fetch_row($result1))
{
   $userNameResult=$row[0];
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Nice idea. I didnt know that..hmm..I can use a numeric array too. I think your answer is the best

Comment: @Dmitry he has a very stupid addition to his answer, making it much worse.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this:

```
$result1=mysql_query(" SELECT COUNT(*) AS result FROM users WHERE user_name='$userName'") or exit(mysql_error());

if($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
   {
       $userNameResult=$row['result'];
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $userNameResult=$row[0];
```

that's all

However, I suspect that it's a nested query, running in the loop?
You should get that number in the parent query, using JOIN in this case.